# RESTful service orchestration using spring MVC and Apache Camel

Tags: spring-mvc, apache-camel, orchestration

i am trying to do REST Service orchestraction using spring MVC and Apache camel. The basic idea is if some one calls a url as http://localhost:8080/context/associateVerify?ssn=value1&param2=value2, it should call webservice as http://localhost:8080/AssociateVerify/ssn?ssn=value, sameway if someone call http://localhost:8080/context/store?storeNum=value1 it should call http://localhost:8080/StoreInfo/store?storeNum=value & so On. I tried searching on net, but couldnt a detail example which would help me start with.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to redirect url to a different service ? Please elaborate

Comment: i am ok even if redirect and get the response which will go as output, but yes context will be same.

Answer (score 0):

UrlRewriteFilter might help you. Its a filter that is equivalent of mod_rewrite module of apache https. You could find more info at http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ and http://nematodes.org/martin/2010/02/04/301-permanent-redirect-with-tomcat-howto/